# Webpack: how to shim implicit MyGlobal references with window.MyGlobal?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

How can I setup webpack/babel so it shims implicit global variables like `MyGlobal` with explicit window references like `window.MyGlobal`? Basically, I'd like to bypass the `use strict` restriction on implicit this globals for a predefined set of "common global variables" in this codebase.

- Decades old browser-side JS codebase transpiled using webpack and babel 7.
- Mix of CJS "scripts" and ESM "modules", all using .js extension, trying to transition step-wise toward all ESM.
- Babel is configured to use `sourceType: "unambiguous"` which decides a file is a module if it uses an import or export.
- This means when I convert a file to use import/export statements it becomes a module, and operates with `use strict` which forbids implicit globals.

As I transition the codebase, I'd like to setup webpack to shim a defined list of implicit globals with their `window.MyGlobal` equivalent. This prevents having to do "all or nothing" large PRs that break the world.

Comment: What I did in a similar situation: 1) Make a new file globals.js that has no "use strict" statement and initializes all the needed globlas as MyGlobal = 123. 2) Put an import "./globals" statement in the main source file (import with side-effect of declaring the globals). No need to change webpack.config in this case. Will that solve your problem?